# Javascript back button with confirm

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to implement a back button onto a form I am designing which when pressed results in a confirmation popup allowing the user to select ok or cancel. The code I have for this button so far is as follows.

```
function goBack(){
    window.history.back();
    }
<button type="back" value="back" onclick="goBack()">Back</button>
```

The issue I am having is that most elements of the form are set as required, and therefore when the back button is clicked, the form asks for all fields to be completed first, please could someone show me how to get the button to go back without requesting the form to be completed first. Thanks

Comment: Somewhere you have code that probably uses something like `onbeforeunload` that is requesting the form to be completed, the browser doesn't do this on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

I only use the button for submitting a form, for this, input type button works properly.

```
<input type="button" onClick="javascript:history.back();" value="back" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no type="back" for the buttons. Just use:

```
<button value="back" onclick="goBack()">Back</button>
```

or

```
<input type="button" onclick="goback()" value="Back">
```

or to be sure use a link:

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">Back</a>
```

Just don't use type="Submit" and make sure you don't have any functions that call form inputs validation when you leave that page!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `back` is not a valid `type` for a button. If you do not want the form to be submitted use the `button` type. This should solve your problem.

```js
function goBack(){
  if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
    window.history.back();  
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <!-- inputs here -->
  <input required />
  <button type='button' onclick='goBack()'>Back</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The code now works and takes me to the previous page. Thanks for your reply, much appreciated.